# "Edit layout" form missing revision log message field

Tags: 8

When I edit the layout for a given node it is missing a log message field in the revision area. Is anybody else seeing this or am I alone? In trying to diagnose:

- Where that particular revision log field would be defined to check if it's defined at all. If it's not then this is probably a core bug that should be addressed.
- If it does exist, where this particular form is defined to make sure that the revision log field is actually being included in the form definition.

Any insights on the above? I'm using the lightning distribution, so it's possible that there's some sort of override going on there, but I figured I should be checking in core first just in case.

The overall goal here for bounty award is to have a functional revision log message field on the form.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added my initial patch to the issue - https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3033516#comment-13136184

Adding this chunk to the `init` method of the `OverridesEntityForm` seems to do the trick, at least for nodes. We'll see what core maintainers come back with, but hopefully this can help you in the meantime.

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function init(FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::init($form_state);

    $form_display = EntityFormDisplay::collectRenderDisplay($this->entity, $this->getOperation(), FALSE);
    $form_display->setComponent(OverridesSectionStorage::FIELD_NAME, [
      'type' => 'layout_builder_widget',
      'weight' => -10,
      'settings' => [],
    ]);

    $section_storage = $this->getSectionStorage();
    $entity = $section_storage->getContextValue('entity');
    $entity_type = $entity->getEntityType();
    if ($entity_type->isRevisionable()) {
      $revision_log_message_form_item = $entity_type->getRevisionMetadataKey('revision_log_message');
      $log_field_definition = $entity->getFieldDefinition($revision_log_message_form_item);
      $log_field_revision_message_form_data = $log_field_definition->getDisplayOptions('form');
      $form_display->setComponent($revision_log_message_form_item, $log_field_revision_message_form_data);  
    }

    $this->setFormDisplay($form_display, $form_state);
  }
```

Comment: Nice, but I think you need to check first if the entity supports revision

Comment: Good call - Updated the post here, and the D.O. ticket. Also updated with recommendation from Tim Plunkett (core maintainer) to use `$this->getSectionStorage()`

Comment: Thanks @TylerFahey, since you've got the issue queue rolling I'm accepting this as the answer. If anybody else hits this, check the issue noted above for the most up to date patch.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bug in the Layout Builder Module.
I found an [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3033516) on the Drupal Core issue queue with the same exact behaviour. Strangely, it is marked as "Closed (cannot reproduce)"
I did create a clean Drupal 8 instance, enabled Layout Builder for the basic page content type with enabled revisions.
I saw the same exact behaviour. Additionally, log messages were only saved with "edit" form and not with the "layout" form. So, it is definitely a core layout builder module bug and not related to the distribution you're using.

---

**Suggestion**: [Open](https://www.drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/drupal) a new ticket on the Drupal Core issue tracker

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation on this. I came across the issue before but couldn't find it again -- glad I'm not going completely crazy. If nobody comes through here with a further fix before the bounty ends I'll award it to you.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to look for a fix, but it seems related to how Layout builder loads the entity form. I'll keep you posted if I find anything

Comment: Agreed. I'm lost as to how it generates the form. I can't seem to find its definition anywhere